# How to show that the equivalence classes of $R$ correspond to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, relations, equivalence-relations

Let p and q be any two distinct prime numbers and define the relation $aRb$ on integers $a,b$ by: $aRb$ iff $b-a$ is divisible by both $p$ and $q$. For this relation $R$: $\\$

(1) Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation. $\\$

(2) Show that the equivalence classes of $R$ correspond to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$. That is: $[a] = [b]$ as equivalence classes of $R$ if and only if $[a] = [b]$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$. Check for yourself that (1) does hold still, but (2) need not be true if $p, q$ are not prime. $\\$

You may use the following lemma: $\\$

*If p is prime and $p\mid mn$, then $p \mid m$ or $p \mid n$.*

Indicate in your proof the step(s) for which you invoke this lemma. $\\$

I proved part (1), but I didn't use the lemma yet, so I'm pretty sure I need to use it in part (2), but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: When do $a$ and $b$ belong to the same class?

Comment: I just learned about equivalence classes, so I'm still figuring out exactly what it is, but do $a$ and $b$ belong to the same class if there is a relation aRb and bRa?

Comment: Right, but that's not what I meant. (Note that equivalence classes are defined given an equivalence relation, in particular, $aRb$ iff $bRa$)

Comment: What I meant was, that under the given relation $R$, $a\equiv_R b$ iff $pq|(b-a)$. Do you see why this is true?

Comment: Because according to $R$, $a \equiv _R b$ iff $p \mid (b-a)$ and $q \mid (b-a)$?

Comment: 2 is wrong.  [a] = [b] iff a - b in Z$_{pq}$.

Comment: So you are saying I can't show (2) because it is wrong?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, how do you mean? Of course the question is correct

Comment: '[a] = [b] as elements of' is unacceptably sloppy.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, I literally copied the assignment. How exactly is this wrong? What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: @Neri.  See previous answer.